# Auto resizing qt application. (main window)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I've recently started development in qt and so far it's going good. Now my question is : can I auto re-size qt application as per my screen resolution ? Say, I 've a main window designed for 1366 x 768. And it works for one system. While porting it to another system which supports 1280 x 800 or 800 x 600, is there an easy way to do it ? without changing UI design in creator ?

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do this (for example put it in the mainWindow's constructor)

```
this->showMaximized();
```

Anyways you can simply get resolution of current screen with this code:

```
qDebug() << QApplication::desktop()->size();
```

And `QWidget` have `resize()` method. `QMainWindow` inherits `QWidget`, so you can use `resize()` in your mainWindow.

Comment: Does using resize in QMainWindow constructor help all the components in that window as well ?

Comment: @dastaan your question was about resizing window accordingly to the screen size and I wrote answer already. If you want that all widgets which mainWindow contains will be automatically resized accordingly to the new size of mainWindow you should use QLayout. This class was created for this purpose. You can create Layouts in Qt Designer or you can write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Qt (and many other UI toolkit) solve auto resize problem with a layout manager, it depend on how do you design your UI to choose a layout or mix them. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Comment: Thanks. It's worth going for layout.